# What is a Paragraph (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Paragraph)

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto, word-addins

What exactly is a paragraph in the context of `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word`? I believe it is more than what the Office Word app itself considers a paragraph because the paragraphs count from the app is less than the paragraphs count returned by the `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Paragraphs` collection. Any link that explains this will be appreciated.

**UPDATE!**

For example, the Microsoft Word App paragraph count (returned by clicking the word count info on the status bar) shows *40 paragraphs* in the document as shown in the image below (with a red arrow pointing to the count).

[image: Paragraph count gotten inside microsoft Word application]

The paragraph count gotten using the c# programming code in Word VSTO Add in on the other hand returns 52 paragraphs. Then every empty space (new line break without a text) added to the document (by pressing the ENTER button on the keyboard) counts as an increase in the number of paragraphs that gets returned here but that of the Word Application remains constant at 40 paragraphs. The image below shows the paragraphs count in the Visual Studio `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine` output.

[image: Paragraphs count shown with the yellow arrow and how it increases with every empty space added]

The code used in getting the paragraph count is:

```
Word.Document myDoc = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument;
        Word.Paragraphs paragraphs = myDoc.Paragraphs;
        int numberOfParagraphs = paragraphs.Count;
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("This is the number of paragraphs returned: " + numberOfParagraphs);
```

It is based on this that I need a complete understanding of which elements from the document a `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Paragraphs`collection actually represents; especially those that are not normally counted as paragraphs by the Microsoft word application.

Comment: Have you tested it? When you create a document with two paragraphs, how many are in the `Paragraphs` collection? When you enumerate them, what are the differences?

Comment: [Represents a single paragraph in a selection, range, or document.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.word.paragraph?view=word-pia)

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how do you get the Word paragraph count and how do you get the Interop paragraph count?

Comment: The paragraph in the Word app is the visible text. Fields and inline shapes etc. are included in the internal paragraph object.

Comment: @RufusL, I have tested it. I have 40 paragraphs count on the app but 52 in the collection. There are stuff that are not considered paragraph by the Word App Paragraph count but are actually seen as paragraphs by the paragraph collection. Every _ENTER_ clicked on the keyboard for example is counted as an additional paragraph by `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Paragraphs` even without any text added but you need to add a text for such to be considered a paragraph by the Word Application. That is why I need a good understanding of the entire differences.

Comment: @ikerbera, I have updated the question with some details about how I get the two counts, please check.

Comment: @Boeryepes, okay. I think I am beginning to understand. That is why I need a link that explains the differences thoroughly. Thanks all for the contribution.

Answer (score 0):

After a little bit of testing, I think I've got an answer.

> This is as much an answer as it is an educated guess, so feel free to
>   correct anything wrong that you spot.

So you can actually show in word the line breaks, which defines what a paragraph is.

[image: Enters shown in Word]

Now, as you can see in the picture, I have 8 line breaks but it only shows 1 paragraph in word.

So, my educated guess is that Word counts as paragraphs only the line breaks that have something written and Interop shows every line break disregarding if the text is written is null or empty.

You can actually test this hypothesis by showing the line break char in word and counting them by hand. Or, in your code, you can loop through the paragraphs and count every paragraph that has no text. If the sum of that count plus the number of paragraphs that Word shows is the same as the count of paragraphs in your code then my hypothesis is right.

If not I'm very wrong

Comment: As explained in my question and comments above, yes the code recognizes every paragraph mark as a paragraph regardless of whether it has text or it's empty. But that's not all! Further check shows that a line break with inline shape but no text is still not seen as a paragraph by Word. If a table of empty cells is added to a new line break, it is still not recognized as paragraph by Word but **the code** counts each added raw as a paragraph and each empty cell as a paragraph. Word only counts the cells containing texts as paragraphs. Meanwhile still on it. Thanks for the contribution please!